# Kivy. Position of GridLayout inside ScrollView

Tags: kivy

I give up. I think I have tried everything I possibly could. I need some explatanion how to position nested layouts classes. In below code I need these labels to be positioned in the center of the screen. Anything I've tried leaves the `Labels` on the left side.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv = """

<StorageLabel@Label>
    background_normal: ''
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 65, 50
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (1, 0, 0.5, 1) 
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    halign: "left"
    valign: "middle"    

<Storage@BoxLayout>
    ScrollView:
        size_hint_x: 1
        bar_width: 10
        scroll_type: ['bars', 'content']
        bar_color: [0, 0, 0, 1]
        bar_inactive_color: [0, 0, 0, 1]
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}
        GridLayout:

            cols: 3
            size_hint_y: None
            size: self.minimum_size
            height: self.minimum_height

            StorageLabel:
                text: '1m'

            StorageLabel:
                text: '2m'

            StorageLabel:
                text: '3m'

Storage:

"""

sm = Builder.load_string(kv)

class Main(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to center the `Labels` is to let the `GridLayout` size and position them. This results in a larger `width` for each `Label`, but they are centered:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv = """

<StorageLabel@Label>
    background_normal: ''
    # leave size_hint_x at default of 1
    size_hint_y: None
    height: 50
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (1, 0, 0.5, 1) 
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<Storage@BoxLayout>
    ScrollView:
        size_hint_x: 1
        bar_width: 10
        scroll_type: ['bars', 'content']
        bar_color: [0, 0, 0, 1]
        bar_inactive_color: [0, 0, 0, 1]
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}
        GridLayout:
            cols: 3
            # add some padding and spacing
            padding: 5
            spacing: 5
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height

            StorageLabel:
                text: '1m'

            StorageLabel:
                text: '2m'

            StorageLabel:
                text: '3m'

Storage:

"""

sm = Builder.load_string(kv)

class Main(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main().run()
```

If you want the labels to be your original size, then you can place each in its own `Layout` (perhaps a `FloatLayout`), and let the `GridLayout` size and position those `Layouts`:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv = """

<StorageLabel@Label>
    background_normal: ''
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 65, 50
    # position the label in the center of its FloatLayout
    pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5}
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (1, 0, 0.5, 1) 
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

<Storage@BoxLayout>
    ScrollView:
        size_hint_x: 1
        bar_width: 10
        scroll_type: ['bars', 'content']
        bar_color: [0, 0, 0, 1]
        bar_inactive_color: [0, 0, 0, 1]
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5}
        GridLayout:
            cols: 3
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            # set the default row height to the height of the Labels
            row_default_height: 50

            FloatLayout:
                StorageLabel:
                    text: '1m'

            FloatLayout:
                StorageLabel:
                    text: '2m'

            FloatLayout:
                StorageLabel:
                    text: '3m'

Storage:

"""

sm = Builder.load_string(kv)

class Main(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main().run()
```